# PySpark: how to stop executors with zero active tasks?

Tags: pyspark

I run PySpark with a CPU grid that has many hosts and several cores per host. When I launch a framework, many tasks can be allocated to a single host. I have noticed that when all of the tasks on a host have finished, the host will still hold onto one CPU until the framework has completed. Why is that happening? Is it possible to change this behavior so that it doesn't hold onto cores that have no associated tasks?

Comment: I'm not sure what you asked is doable. The reason for it's behavior is simple though. As the cost of re-initializing an executor is more it doesn't want to shutdown one before making sure the application ended successfully. Also in case of a task-failure/slow-task-execution on some other node, the executors that are idle will be used to re-execute the lost/slow-running task.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Those idle cores end up being a big waste for my purposes, though. Let's say I have 10,000 tasks. 1,000 get launched at the beginning. With my Mesos scheduler, frameworks using fewer cores have a higher priority. So once those 1,000 are done, let's say 500 are being held onto (one per host) that have no active tasks. That drops me down in the priority, so I only get a small number of more cores. So quickly, the number of inactive cores becomes higher than the number of active cores. I was thinking one solution would be to stop holding onto inactive cores. Any other ideas?